# Two conditionalPanel's in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I have a Shiny application and I've created the following `conditionalPanel`'s:

```
    conditionalPanel(condition="output.levels",
                      numericInput("centerpoints", "Number of center points", value=0, min=0, max=25)),
    conditionalPanel(condition="!output.levels",
                     numericInput("centerpoints", "Number of center points", value=0, min=0, max=0))
```

If output.levels is TRUE I want to select between 0 and 25 center points. Otherwise, the number of center points must be 0.

The problem is that if the condition is TRUE, I select more than 0 center points and then the condition becomes FALSE, Shiny keeps the center points selected before in stead of 0.

Is there a way to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing comes from having two almost identical elements in your ui, that share the same id. Conditional panels only hide your elements, but they are still there in the document. So your first `numericInput` will always be the one registered by Shiny and the second one will not be bound (i.e. will not send its input) to Shiny because of the duplicate id.

I advise you to implement the situation in a different way. There are functions in Shiny that let you change some existing ui element when the app is all set up. Those functions are `updateXxxInput` and you can change any variable there is in the corresponding input element. Since your only target is to change the `max` value of the `numericInput`, we can do this easily from the server, where we can `observe` the `levels` or any other variable. In the code below, I used a simple checkbox. The command for changing the `max` value is `updateNumericInput(session, "centerpoints", max = 0)`. Note that this only changes the one attribute of you input. This is a huge advantage over re-rendering UI elements, since you don't have to keep track what all other attributes are.

The `updateXxxInput` functions are very useful, so give it a try!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    numericInput("centerpoints", "Number of center points", value=0, min=0, max=25),
    checkboxInput("changeCenterpoints", "Cap maximum at 0")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$changeCenterpoints, {
    if(input$changeCenterpoints){
      updateNumericInput(session, "centerpoints", max = 0, value = 0)
    }else{
      updateNumericInput(session, "centerpoints", max = 25)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try with UpdateXxxInput functions.